# I'm trying to hide a button from other sockets in node.js. After the buttons is clicked my a player i don't want other players to be able to click it

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need to be able to remove the buttons from the DOM when a player clicks a seat.  this way two players cannot take the same seat.  all buttons should be hidden on the client side after a player sits down so they cannot move seats.

server side

```
   socket.on('seat1',function(){
       player.x = 380
       player.y = 300
       player.number = 1
       console.log(player)

    socket.emit('seat1',function(){
        hideSeatButtons();
    })

   });

     socket.on('seat2',function(){
       player.x = 380
       player.y = 100
       player.number = 2
       console.log(player)


   });

client side

   var seat1 = function(){
        socket.emit('seat1',{

        });

   }

    var seat2 = function(){
        socket.emit('seat2',{

        });

   }


  var hideSeatButtons = function(){
        document.getElementById("seat1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("seat2").style.display = "none";
   }
```

Comment: There will always be a race condition here since two users could click the same button at about the same time (before their client was notified that someone else clicked it).  So, what you need to do is to click the button and then tell the server you've clicked it.  The server will respond back whether the click was successful or not or whether someone else already clicked it before you and the client can behave accordingly.  When the server receives a successful click on a button, it can broadcast to all the other clients that that button is now taken and the clients can behave accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have everything set up properly, you will need to listen on the client side for the event you are emitting from the server. Rather than passing a function when emitting, try passing a value or an object (I changed the name of the event being sent to the client to avoid confusion with the event intended for the server):

```
socket.on('seat1',function(){
   player.x = 380
   player.y = 300
   player.number = 1
   console.log(player)

   socket.emit('hideSeats', {
       seatIndex: 1,
       playerNumber: player.number
   });
});
```

On the client you can listen for 'hideSeats' and call your client code function from there.

```
socket.on('hideSeats', function(obj) {
    if (obj.playerNumber === player.number) {
        hideSeatButtons();
    } else {
        hideSingleSeatButton(obj.seatIndex);
    }
});
```

This assumes you write a function to hide a single seat -which is what I think you would want to do for any player who is not the one who chose a seat. For the player who chose a seat, you hide all seats.

Does this approach cover your use case?